How to implement a decimal quantity dropdown in WooCommerce block-based cart page, similar to the product page
On the product page, my dropdown quantity fields, which I defined as decimal according to category, are working and are added to the cart successfully. However, I have problems with quantity on the block-based cart page.It does not allow input and decimal input, I want to do the same on the cart page.
function woocommerce_quantity_input( $args = array(), $product = null, $echo = true ) {
  
   if ( is_null( $product ) ) {
      $product = $GLOBALS['product'];
   }

   $defaults = array(
      'input_id'    => uniqid( 'quantity_' ),
      'input_name'  => 'quantity',
      'input_value' => '1',
      'classes'     => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_classes', array( 'input-text', 'qty', 'text' ), $product ),
      'product_name' => $product ? $product->get_title() : '',
   );

   $args = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults ), $product );

   $custom_values = array( 0.5, 1.5, 10, 20 ); // Varsayılan quantity değerleri

   if ( has_term( 46, 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
       $custom_values = array( 23, 35, 40, 50 ); // Kategori 46 için değerler
   } elseif ( has_term( 33, 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
       $custom_values = array( 5, 15, 20, 30 ); // Kategori 33 için değerler
   }

   $options = '';
    
   foreach ( $custom_values as $value ) {
      $selected = ( $value == $args['input_value'] ) ? 'selected' : '';
      $options .= '<option value="' . esc_attr( $value ) . '"' . $selected . '>' . esc_html( $value ) . '</option>';
   }
     
   $string = '<div class="quantity"><span>Qty</span><select name="' . esc_attr( $args['input_name'] ) . '" class="' . esc_attr( implode( ' ', $args['classes'] ) ) . '">' . $options . '</select></div>';
 
   if ( $echo ) {
      echo $string;
   } else {
      return $string;
   }
}

With these hooks, I can add the product to the cart as decimal, but the input fields on the cart page do not allow decimal input, and when the cart is updated, decimal numbers are converted to integers.
// Removes the WooCommerce filter, that is validating the quantity to be an int
remove_filter('woocommerce_stock_amount', 'intval');

// Add a filter, that validates the quantity to be a float
add_filter('woocommerce_stock_amount', 'floatval');


My quantity field on the normal cart page is the same as the code on the product page. How can I make the quantity field on the block-based cart page look like the code I made for the product page?

WooCommerce mini-cart, cart and checkout blocks, only allow very few customizations, so you will not be able to make it for cart blocks. The only possible  way is to switch back to classic cart (legacy shortcode).
